# Powershell : Connect-partnercenter Error: ClientId is not a Guid

Tags: powershell

Here is my problem, I want to get the list of people with administrator role on O365 partner center while going through Azure Automation for scheduled task.

One of the first problems, is that access to the partner center is that you have to have the MFA activated on the account that does it. So I created an Azure application by following the information here: https://www.cyberdrain.com/connect-to-exchange-online-automated-when-mfa-is-enabled-using-the-secureapp-model/

The application has been created successfully, so I run the command given on the Microsoft site at the bottom (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/multi-factor-auth?view= partnercenterps-3.0):

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$refreshToken = '<refreshToken>'

Connect-PartnerCenter -ApplicationId 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' -Credential $credential -RefreshToken $refreshToken
```

The problem is that when I run this command, this is the message I get:

```
Connect-PartnerCenter : Error: ClientId is not a Guid.
At line:8 char:1
+ Connect-PartnerCenter -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -Credential $cred ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-PartnerCenter], MsalClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Commands.ConnectPartnerCenter
```

I have searched everywhere, I do not understand where this problem comes from.

Have some of you already encountered this problem or have another solution to get the list of admin people on the partner center?

Thank you